# Gate::allows not working in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a problem on Laravel 5.3 with the new `Gate::allows` method.

Here is my `AuthServiceProvider.php` for the test:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  /**
   * The policy mappings for the application.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $policies = [
      'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
  ];

  /**
   * Register any authentication / authorization services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function boot()
  {
      $this->registerPolicies();

      Gate::define('settings', function ($user)
      {
          return true;
      });
  }
}
```

Normally, whatever the user's role, everybody can access the settings.

But this always display 'no' instead of 'ok'.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Gate;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SettingsController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct(Request $request)
  {
    echo Gate::allows('settings') ? 'ok' : 'no';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Laravel 5.3 we can't access session or the authenticated user in controllers constructors, as stated in the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors)

Since the `Gate` facades uses the `User`model, probably it tries to access the user but it's not still ready in the constructor of your controller

So, you should consider using a middleware to check the `Gate`. You can also use a Closure based middleware directly in the controller constructor:

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        echo Gate::allows('settings') ? 'ok' : 'no';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to be authorized. If laravel not see user, it returns false.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, from what I understand **AuthServiceProvider** is namespaced under **\App\Providers** so if you put classes in $policies properties without global namespace they also be namespaced under **\App\Providers** .. so in your case **\App\Providers\App\Model** and **\App\Providers\Policies\ModelPolicy**.

To sum up, try $policies properties like this:

```
  protected $policies = [
      \App\Model::class => \App\Policies\ModelPolicy::class,
  ];
```

Hope that helps :)

PS. It's my first activity here, so hello everyone and all the best in the new year.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be authorized. If laravel not see user, it returns false. Or do you use guard. I have it is because of this and had a similar problem.